# Customising spacing of a binary operator

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I defined a new binary operator using `\rule` to create a custom symbol similar to `\mid` but a bit thicker. I originally gave it `\mathrel` spacing (the same as `\mid`), but I find that tends to give a bit too much space around the operator, so I changed it to `\mathbin`.

```
\newcommand{\mg}{\mathbin{\rule[-2.5pt]{1.25pt}{10pt}}}
```

With `\mathbin` spacing it looks fine most of the time, but the `\mathbin` spacing seems a bit "squishier", and in inline math it sometimes gets a squished up a bit too much, as you can see here. (MWE code below.)

[image]

So I'm wondering if I can control the spacing around this operator a bit more precisely. I would like it to look similar to `\mathbin` but to have a greater lower bound on how much the typesetting system can reduce the space in inline math.

Here's the MWE, which generates the example shown above.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mg}{\mathbin{\rule[-2.5pt]{1.25pt}{10pt}}}

\begin{document}

Here is the `mg' command in an equation, which looks good:
\begin{equation}
 \psi(a\mg b)
\end{equation}

It also looks fine most of the time in inline math $\psi(a\mg b)$.

But sometimes it looks a bit sort of jammed together, e.g.\ $\psi(a\mg b)\,\phi(c\mg b)\,\theta(d\mg e)$.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

`\mathbin` is no substitute for `\mathrel`. The spacing rules for binary operations and relations are very different. If you really want a different spacing (I don't think so), you can define a macro for the whole complex, assuming that `\mg` is always infix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mg}{\mathpalette\mg@\relax}
\newcommand{\mg@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$#1|$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$\m@th#1\mspace{18mu}$}%
  \rule[-\dp\z@]{0.125\wd\tw@}{\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\DeclareRobustCommand{\mgrel}[2]{%
  {#1}%
  \nonscript\mspace{2mu}\mspace{2mu}%
  \mg
  \nonscript\mspace{2mu}\mspace{2mu}%
  {#2}%
}

\begin{document}

It looks fine most of the time in inline math $\psi(\mgrel{a}{b})$.

And it doesn't jam even if the line is compressed, 
e.g.\ $\psi(\mgrel{a}{b})\,\phi(\mgrel{c}{b})\,\theta(\mgrel{d}{e})$.

It also works in subscripts: $A_{(\mgrel{a}{b})}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Math atoms of type `op`, `bin`, and `rel` are generally (depending on what precedes and follows these math atoms) surrounded by whitespace governed by the parameters `\thinmuskip`, `\medmuskip`, and `\thickmuskip`, respectively. The default values of these parameters in most (possibly all) LaTeX document classes I'm familiar with are `3mu`, `4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu`, and `5mu plus 5mu`. (`mu` is defined as 1/18 of the width of the letter "M", aka `1em`.) In words, `\thinmuskip` has a fixed value (it's a "length parameter" in TeX jargon), `\thickmuskip` has a stretch component but no shrinkage component (its minimal value is 5mu and its maximal value is 10mu), and `\medmuskip` has both a stretch and a shrinkage component (it's a "glue parameter" in TeX jargon: Its minimal value is 0mu and its maximal value is 6mu).

You've chosen to assign type `math-bin` to the `\mg` macro. As a result, the amount of whitespace around the symbol can be as little as 0mu, i.e., no space at all.

My advice to you would be to *not* touch the value of `\medmuskip`, as it's used in all kinds of places and calculations. In view of the facts that (a) `\mg` is supposed to play a role akin to that of `\mid`, (b) `\mid`'s math status is `math-rel`, and (c) `\thickmuskip` has no shrinkage component, I would assign math-rel status to `\mg` as well (and get used to `5mu` rather than `4mu` of separation).

Comment: Hmm. +1 for the very helpful explanation, but I don't find the 5mu very easy to get used to - that's why I changed it to `\mathbin` in the first place. I don't like the mathrel spacing much for `\mid` either, when it's used for conditional probabilities - it just seems like a bit too much space to me in that case. (But `|` definitely has too little space around it.)

Comment: @Nathaniel - If it's purely a whitespace padding issue, i.e., if you don't actually care whether the operator has status `math-bin` or `math-rel`, you should simply drop the `\mathbin` wrapper entirely and provide the following macro definition: `\newcommand{\mg}{\mkern4mu\rule[-2.5pt]{1.25pt}{10pt}\mkern4mu}`.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to look much better throughout the document.